# changing html cell colour back to default automatically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a html table where the cell colours are changed dependent of data pulled in from mysql using php and the colours update on the table without having to refresh the page however the issue im currently having is the cells start off grey but when the value has stopped being pulled into the html the cell doesnt go back to grey any help on how i can do this?

Sorry i should have included the css

current code is as followed:

css:

```
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
cellpadding: 2;
cellspacing: 2;
width: "100%";
height: "100%";
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 48px;
background-color: #8F8F8F;
}
```

html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location);
        });
    });

    function upateTable() {
        $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item);
                $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', 
item.location);
            });
        });
    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(upateTable, 15000);
});
```

Comment: css classes are so much easier.... `$("td").removeClass("foo bar world")` and just add the classes in the each loop Only option you have is to loop over all the cells and change the color to gray.

Comment: @epascarello i tried adding and then removing the class however this didnt work i used the following code is this correct ?
inital ajax
$(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', 
item.location);.addclass(classname);

$(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', 
item.location);.removeClass(classname);

Comment: No, the class is so you do not need o use the background color. Instead of setting color you set a class on the element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a default class that's a grey background, then make a reset function that brings all cells back to this default color before you get the answer you your query to PHP?

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: With a function that loops through all table cells and removes the background color before reloading the data.

Comment: sorry im not very good when it comes to coding haha i dont know how to do that

Comment: You can loop through each `<td>` cells and remove the background color using `$('td').css('background-color', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you set the colour to Grey. Your best bet is to include code in the updateTable() function.

You can use a jquery filter to pull out all the non-grey cells and turn them grey before recolouring based on your ajax as you do there.

```
$('td').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('background-color') != '#8F8F8F';
}).css('background-color','#8F8F8F');
```

Alternatively using classes I would recommend:

In your line where you set the background color to also set a class which is used to flag the coloured cells

```
$(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
```

then later you can simply uncolour all of the flagged cells

```
$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
```

Comment: sorry i hadnt included the css would the above render the css obsolete?

Comment: see my edit above, In the first section i have simply changed grey to the specific colour you are using. I have also offered an alternative approach using classes.

Comment: that worked great however the issue i now have is if i bring the item.beacon back into the equation the cell stays grey it may just be where i have added the code though